# Is there an example on NON-namespace configuration for Oauth for Spring Security?

Tags: oauth, spring-security

For a variety of reasons, we cannot use Spring's namespace configuration. Is there an example of the OAuth 2.0 configuration that doesn't use the namespace configuration mechanism? Mostly I am trying to figure out which filter need to be included in the filter chain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is what I set up to get the basic OAuth 2.0 flow working (essentially the same as in the Tonr/Sparklr demo). Our security setup is complicated, so I'll only reproduce the relevant snippets below.

First, the filter chain order:

```
BasicUserApprovalFilter, SecurityContextPersistenceFilter, LogoutFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter, RequestCacheAwareFilter, SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter, AnonymousAuthenticationFilter, SessionManagementFilter, ExceptionTranslationFilter, OAuth2ExceptionHandlerFilter, VerificationCodeFilter, OAuth2AuthorizationFilter, OAuth2ProtectedResourceFilter, FilterSecurityInterceptor
```

Note that the `AnonymousAuthenticationFilter` is *absolutely required* even if you don't use it anywhere else.

Now the supporting beans:

```
<bean id="oauth2ExceptionTranslationFilter" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.OAuth2ExceptionHandlerFilter"/>

<bean id="oauth2VerificationCodeFilter" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.verification.VerificationCodeFilter">
    <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetailsService"/>
    <property name="verificationServices" ref="verificationCodeServices"/>
    <property name="userApprovalHandler" ref="oauth2UserApprovalFilter"/>

    <property name="unapprovedAuthenticationHandler">
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
            <!-- This is where you define your confirmation page -->
            <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/oauth/confirm.action"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="oauth2AuthorizationFilter" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.OAuth2AuthorizationFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler">
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.OAuth2AuthorizationSuccessHandler">
            <property name="tokenServices" ref="tokenServices"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="oauth2ProtectedResourceFilter" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.OAuth2ProtectedResourceFilter">
    <property name="tokenServices" ref="tokenServices"/>
</bean>

<bean id="tokenServices" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.InMemoryOAuth2ProviderTokenServices">
    <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true"/>
</bean>

<bean id="clientDetailsService" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.InMemoryClientDetailsService">
    <property name="clientDetailsStore">
        <map>
            <entry key="tonr">
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.BaseClientDetails">
                    <property name="clientId" value="tonr"/>
                    <property name="authorizedGrantTypes">
                        <list>
                            <value>authorization_code</value>
                            <value>refresh_token</value>
                        </list>
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="verificationCodeServices" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.verification.InMemoryVerificationCodeServices"/>

<bean id="oauth2VerificationAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.verification.VerificationCodeAuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="verificationServices" ref="verificationCodeServices"/>
</bean>

<bean id="oauth2AccessGrantAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.AccessGrantAuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetailsService"/>
</bean>

<bean id="oauth2RefreshAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.refresh.RefreshAuthenticationProvider"/>
```

Note that the services (client, token, verification code) are just the supplied in memory versions. You'll need to create your own versions to be persistent.

Finally, you need to tie the providers into your authentication manager:

```
<bean id="authenticationManager" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
        <property name="providers">
            <list>
                <ref local="daoAuthenticationProvider"/>
                <ref local="oauth2AccessGrantAuthenticationProvider"/>
                <ref local="oauth2VerificationAuthenticationProvider"/>
                <ref local="oauth2RefreshAuthenticationProvider"/>
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationProvider">
                    <property name="key" value="mykey"/>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the filters that are firing for me in my namespace-based OAuth 2.0 provider config.   You can get them by setting up namespace and turning on debug logging on spring security.

```
firing Filter: 'BasicUserApprovalFilter'
firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'
firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
firing Filter: 'OAuth2ExceptionHandlerFilter'
firing Filter: 'VerificationCodeFilter'
firing Filter: 'OAuth2AuthorizationFilter'
firing Filter: 'OAuth2ProtectedResourceFilter'
firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
```

Comment: Thanks,this is helpful. Still missing are the various supporting beans (authentication providers, etc.) but this makes it easier to fill in the blanks.